# Use PHP variable in javascript function within a Smarty template

Tags: javascript, php, smarty

In my HTML file, I'm using a string variable called `{$var}` which is passed from a PHP file.  How could I use `{$var}` in a javascript function within the same html file? I would like to display this variable using the js function.  This is what I have so far:

```
<span id="printHere"></span>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var php_var = {$production};
    $('#printHere').html(php_var);
</script>
```

Comment: you just need to echo it

Comment: Just look at the page source

Comment: I looked at the source code and the variable `{$var}` displays `<span class="itemprop" itemprop="name">Name</span>`

Comment: This question is not a duplicate.  It should not have been closed as a duplicate.  Everyone that voted for this question to be closed as a duplicate isn't paying much attention.

Answer (score 8):

### For PHP

You can echo out the variable directly into your JavaScript.  Just be sure to `json_encode()` it so that data types and escaping are all done automatically.

```
var php_var = <?php echo json_encode($production) ?>;
```

### For Smarty

If you are using Smarty for your templating engine, you want this instead:

```
var php_var = {$production|json_encode nofilter};
```

What this does is disable the HTML escaping of Smarty (with `nofilter`) and passes the value through `json_encode()`.

Comment: Looks better than my! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure `$production` is set. If it is a (javascript) `String` then use:

```
var php_var = '<?php echo addslashes($production); ?>';
```

If it is a `Number` then use

```
var php_var = <?php echo $production; ?>;
```

Comment: may want to add `addslashes()` to that.

Comment: @RyanNaddy, That's only part of the problem.  See my answer with JSON-encoding for the correct solution.

Comment: `{$production}` displays `<span class="itemprop" itemprop="name">Name</span>` Does that count as a string?

Comment: are you using a template engine? (smarty)?

Comment: I would assume this as `{$producetion}` wouldn't output anything if it's just php (or even html)

Comment: If I just type `{$production}` simply in html, it would display Name

Comment: Only if you are using a template engine like smarty

Comment: Use `var php_var = {$production|json_encode nofilter}` like @Brad said.

Comment: Yea, just tried it and nothing is displayed.

Comment: Since `{$production}` is html code, would htmlentities work?

Comment: no this doesn't matter as it is a string